# Postfix expression evaluation: how much stack memory is required?

Tags: c, stack, theory, postfix-notation

I feel like this is a very dumb question but I could not find the answer.

Suppose that we want to evaluate a postfix expression which contains various operators with different arity (for example ADD, SUB, and other operators that can take `N` number of operands). How much stack memory (in terms of number of elements) is required to evaluate a postfix expression built with these operators?

Is there a way to determine the amount of memory that is required?

EDIT: It seems that the question is a bit ambiguous. What I am asking is, what is the maximum number of stack elements that I need for this kind of operation? Can it even be calculated or it could be infinitely many and depends on the expression?

Comment: What's the maximum number of values pushed onto the stack at once fpr the particular expression you're interested in? That's your stack depth.

Comment: @keshlam That's exactly what I am asking! How many??

Comment: i think that in the worst case is n! where n is the number of operators and operands, but is very complex to really calculate the actual value, because it depends on many things.

Comment: @emcas88 -- why would you think O(n!)?  I can't possibly be worse than O(n) (if you store the result of EVERY operator), and should be much less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the expression.  The classical recursive solution for a binary expression is something like (in C code):

```
int maxstack(expression *exp) {
    if (IsLeaf(exp)) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        int left_stack = maxstack(exp->left);
        int right_stack = maxstack(exp->right);
        if (left_stack == right_stack)
            return left_stack + 1;
        else if (left_stack > right_stack)
            return left_stack;
        else
            return right_stack;
    }
}
```

extending this to trinary/nary expressions is relatively straight-forward

Comment: Can we say that it is in the order of something? As previously mentioned in the comment, is it O(n!)? I am really looking for numbers (or worst case scenario evaluations).

Comment: The above function gives you exact numbers for the amount of extra storage needed.  It grows as O(log n) in the size of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

There is no inherent maximum. It depends entirely on the expression you're evaluating.